# Android - Fragments return to their first state after replacing them via FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmentmanager

I have an activity that has 3 tab buttons and each of them will bring their own fragment into screen. And one of the fragmnets has a musicplayer and imagebuttons that changes their icons when i click them. ( like play button changes drawable to pause )

The problem is, when I click this play imagebutton and change tabs and return the tab with musicplayer, the imagebutton resets. I think fragmentmanager.replace method creates a new instance of fragment. How can i avoid this.

Here is my code snippet.

```
public class HomeActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

private LocationTracker lt;
private ImageButton imgbTimeline, imgbProfile, imgbMusic;
private Fragment menufragment = new Plik_MenuFragment();
private Fragment timeline = new Plik_TimelineFragment();
private Fragment profile = new Plik_ProfileFragment();
private Fragment musicPlayer = new Plik_MusicPlayerFragment();
private ViewPager viewpager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    // inner slidemenu setting class executing.
    setInitials();

    // Fragment işleri



    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.slidemenu_container, menufragment);
    ft.add(R.id.homepage_container, profile);
    ft.add(R.id.homepage_container, musicPlayer);
    ft.add(R.id.homepage_container, timeline);
    ft.commit();

    OnClickListener ocl = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.imgbTimeline :
                ft.replace(R.id.homepage_container, timeline);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                imgbTimeline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                imgbProfile.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                imgbMusic.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                break;

            case R.id.imgbProfile :
                ft.replace(R.id.homepage_container, profile);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                imgbTimeline.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                imgbProfile.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                imgbMusic.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                break;

            case R.id.imgbMusic :
                ft.replace(R.id.homepage_container, musicPlayer);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                imgbTimeline.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                imgbProfile.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                imgbMusic.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                break;
                default:
                    break;

            }

            ft.commit();

        }
    };

    imgbTimeline.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    imgbProfile.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    imgbMusic.setOnClickListener(ocl);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you are replacing all time fragments that are in the manager. Try controlling the visible fragment, and use this code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

private LocationTracker lt;
private ImageButton imgbTimeline, imgbProfile, imgbMusic;
private Fragment menufragment = new Plik_MenuFragment();
private Fragment timeline = new Plik_TimelineFragment();
private Fragment profile = new Plik_ProfileFragment();
private Fragment musicPlayer = new Plik_MusicPlayerFragment();
private ViewPager viewpager;
private Fragment visible;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    // inner slidemenu setting class executing.
    setInitials();

    // Fragment işleri
    // SUPOSE timeline is main fragment:
    visible = timeline;


    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.slidemenu_container, menufragment);
    ft.add(R.id.homepage_container, profile);
    ft.add(R.id.homepage_container, musicPlayer);
    ft.add(R.id.homepage_container, timeline);
    ft.commit();

    OnClickListener ocl = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.imgbTimeline :
                ft.hide(visible);
                ft.show(timeline);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                visible = timeline;
                imgbTimeline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                imgbProfile.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                imgbMusic.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

                break;

            case R.id.imgbProfile :
                ft.hide(visible);
                ft.show(profile);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                visible = profile;
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                imgbTimeline.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                imgbProfile.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                imgbMusic.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                break;

            case R.id.imgbMusic :
                ft.hide(visible);
                ft.show(musicPlayer);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                visible = musicPlayer;
                imgbTimeline.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                imgbProfile.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                imgbMusic.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                break;
                default:
                    break;

            }

            ft.commit();

        }
    };

    imgbTimeline.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    imgbProfile.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    imgbMusic.setOnClickListener(ocl);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace):

> When you remove or replace a fragment and add the transaction to the
>   back stack, the fragment that is removed is stopped (not destroyed).
>   If the user navigates back to restore the fragment, it restarts. If
>   you do not add the transaction to the back stack, then the fragment is
>   destroyed when removed or replaced.

So if you're calling ft.addToBackStack() it should not be destroying your Fragments.

Log your [Fragments lifecycle methods](http://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png) to understand better what's happening.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("onResume", "Fragment X");
}
```

And do the same for onPause,

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this -

```
ft.replace(R.id.homepage_container, timeline);
```

Use this -

```
ft.add(R.id.homepage_container, timeline);
```

Now the fragment below will be alive. And if you don't want to unintentionally click the fragment below, add to currents fragment layout top container-

```
android:clickable="true"
```